# Reverse waitforsingleobject exists?

Tags: c, winapi, uwp

Is it possible to wait for an object to became in the non-signaled state - currently my best implementation of this is something like:

```
while (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 40000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
```

Comment: no, it not possible

Comment: It's not possible because there's no need for such a capability.  Waiting for an object to *become* non-signaled is logically no different than waiting for an object to become signaled.  You just have to figure out how to do the signaling.  (Note that the *becoming* non-signaled is important - *being* non-signaled is a state, *becoming* non-signaled is an event. Those are different types of things.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle "*there's no need for such a capability*" - that is just your opinion. There are use cases where this functionality would be useful. For example, I have several apps that perform lengthy operations. They detect when an event object becomes signaled to pause the operations, and then wait for the event object to become unsignaled to resume their work. Being able to detect when a signaled object becomes unsignaled without using a wait loop or a second event object would be beneficial.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'd say useful doesn't mean needed. You even posted why it's not necessary: "using a wait loop or a second event object".  While there may be use-cases that would be easier to implement given the capability, internally they'd almost certainly just be implemented with a second event object.  If such objects were useful enough, I strongly suspect they'd be implemented and available.  It's not as if Microsoft, GNU/FSF, *et al* are adverse to adding features to C or C++.

Comment: @Remy just create two events

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? *Why* do you think you need "Reverse WaitForSingleObject"? If you tell about the bigger image, we could possibly suggest a better approach.